# Different in dynamic and static version of realm

Tags: realm

I want to use realm and I dont know whats so different
 Dynamic framework version and static framework version of realm.
(which one is more popular in usage?)

Is anyone can describe a difference with 'easy' words ??

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is described here: https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#dynamic-realms

But the main difference is that a DynamicRealm is not type-safe and does not enforce your schema. Everything you are specified using Strings, whic means they are slower and more unsafe than the static Realm that uses the type system. So unless you are dealing with really dynamic data or migrations I would encourage you to stay with the static Realm. That way you get the full benefit of a statically typed language like Java, less bugs and faster code.